# Meaning and usage of "can't wait"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In the usage samples of can't wait I have found this description:

> can't wait - to be excited about something ("*I can't wait for the
>   birthday party!*").

The meaning is not quite clear. Is it the present (I'm already on the party and I'm exceited about how it's going) or the future (The party is going to start in the future and there's an air of expectencies).

To me it seems that the second one is correct. I'm not sure if we the first usage is even accaptable.

If we say *I can't wait for sth* is it always an upcoming future event or it may be releated to a present activity as well?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the future. The idea is:

> I can't wait for the birthday party, but I have to (because the party is tomorrow night).

You are very excited about going to the party, and would like it to be as soon as possible.